# How do I stop Chrome from blocking preventDefault on mouse wheel listener?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, scroll

I have a page where i'd like the scroll wheel to have a consistent pixel distance traveled per scroll. I am trying to use a solution I found (with some of my own tweaks) using `preventDefault()` but it looks like Chrome *(and apparently also Safari)* now blocks `preventDefalut()` in a listener type event.

Here's my code for reference:

```
        //force scroll wheel px amount
        $(window).on("wheel mousewheel", function(e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scrollTo(0, scrollY - 100);
                return;
            } else if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scrollTo(0, scrollY + 100);
                return;
            }
        });
```

Is there a workaround for this or even a different solution that could work? (preferably in vanilla js if possible, totally ok if not tho).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that `preventDefault` does not work on chrome and safari?

Comment: Correct, at least inside an event listener. Chrome console says "jquery.min.js:2 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` is still implementing this for support of `passive event listeners`, and is planning to support it for `4.0`.

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2871

You have to use raw `javascript`:

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', handler, {passive: true/false});
```

Comment: This looks like it worked perfectly. I was not aware of the ``{passive: true/false}`` option.

Thanks!